# Moment Duration - expected Number got Object

Tags: vue.js, timespan

My backend returns timespan in the following format:

> "00:34:49.4073541"

I have read and I can use moment.duration to return that data.

I want to display minutes and seconds and disable buttons based on this timeout.

```
<template>
      <countdown :time="this.time">
        <p>Time Remaining： {{ this.time.minutes }} minutes, {{ this.time.seconds }} seconds.</p>
      </countdown>
</template> 

import moment from 'moment'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      otp: '',
      initialOtpSent: false,
      time: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createOtp (bvModalEvt) {

      if (res.data.resetOtpRetriesTimestamp === undefined) {
        this.initialOtpSent = true
        this.$bvToast.toast('The otp has been sent!', {
          title: 'SUCCESS!',
          variant: 'success',
          solid: true,
          static: true,
          noAutoHide: false
        })
        // check on retries timestamp and disable sendotp and resend otp
      } else {
    const timeDuration = moment.duration(res.data.resetOtpRetriesTimestamp)
    this.time = timeDuration
```

The error is:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "time". Expected Number, got
> Object

Comment: This [format is not recognized by moment](https://jsfiddle.net/Dibyanshu/q2n3am5b/4/), can you provide more details, like which database and what is the column type this data is set in?

Comment: Can you show me the count down component code?
There seems to be a problem with the time you receive it through props.

Comment: this is TimeSpan property in C# :         public TimeSpan? ResetOtpRetriesTimestamp { get; set; }

Comment: This is the library I am using : https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown/tree/v1

Comment: @DibyanshuBanerjee - yes it is. The OP is creating a `moment.duration` object, not a `moment` object.  See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the example in [the usage docs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown/tree/v1#usage) for the component you referenced, which shows the `:time` attribute as a number, in terms of milliseconds.

You can change your Moment code to `this.time = timeDuration.asMilliseconds();`

Then change the template to match the format shown in the docs.  For example:

```
<countdown :time="this.time">
  <template slot-scope="props">Time Remaining：{{ props.minutes }} minutes, {{ props.seconds }} seconds.</template>
</countdown>
```

Comment: thank you. I did not know i could use that as miliseconds. I have actually calculated it by using hour and minutes and multiplying all of them to get the miliseconds. Your solution is much cleaner.